# Executing Lines of Code from Main Asyncronously SwiftUI

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui

I am trying to code something in SwiftUI so that it takes a screenshot of the UI, but I want some parts of the view to disappear right before the screenshot is taken so they aren't included. I need these steps to be executed in order so I used

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

                }
```

But I get an error **UI API called from background thread Group**

So then I tried

```
DispatchQueue.main {

}
```

But when I put the three lines of code in there (hide elements, take a screenshot, show elements), they are executed simultaneously. So I'm not sure how else I can make these three lines of code execute one after the other.

Using conditional statements doesn't seem to work either ...

```
while true {
      if self.hideElements != true {
                        self.hideElements = true
                    } else {
                        takeScreenshot()
                        self.hideElements = false
                        break
                    }
                }
```

hideElements is a State variable that sets the opacity of the elements to 0 when set to true

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure I understood. If you want to make something conditionally why don't put that into condition? Would you show in code what you try to do?

Comment: I updated the question, conditional statements aren't working